# Bullet spawn stops/buggs randomly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having some difficulties with my shooting script. Normally the bullets works just fine but sometimes(totally random) I can't shoot any more.
I can see the sprite right beside my character but it doesn't move. And if that happens it can't be fixed until I restart the game.

The weapon Script is on the player

```
public class weaponScript : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform shotPrefab;
public float shootingRate = 0.25f;
private float shootCooldown;
public float xtrans;

void Start(){
    shootCooldown = 0f;
}

void Update(){
    if (shootCooldown > 0){
        shootCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

public void Attack(bool isEnemy)
{
    if (CanAttack){
        if(PinkPlayerControler.playerFaceRight == true)
            xtrans = transform.position.x + 2f;
        else if(PinkPlayerControler.playerFaceRight == false)
            xtrans = transform.position.x - 2f;
        shootCooldown = shootingRate;
        var shotTransform = Instantiate(shotPrefab) as Transform;
        //shotTransform.position = transform.position;
        shotTransform.position = new Vector3(xtrans, transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
    }
}

public bool CanAttack
{
    get{
        return shootCooldown <= 0f;
    }
}
}
```

And the other two on the bullet

```
public class bulletMove : MonoBehaviour {
public Vector2 jumpVector;
public int speed;

void Update(){
    startMovement ();
}

void startMovement(){
    if (PinkPlayerControler.playerFaceRight == true) {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = transform.right.normalized * speed;
        Destroy(this);
    }
    else {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = -transform.right.normalized * speed;
        Destroy(this);
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
    if (other.tag == "bulletDeath" || other.tag == "groundTrap")
        Destroy (this.gameObject);
    else if (other.tag == "destroyByBullet") {
        Debug.Log("blockHit");
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

Shoot Script

```
public class shootScript : MonoBehaviour {

public static int damage = 1;
public static bool hit = false;

void Start()
{
    Destroy(gameObject, 2);
}

void Update(){
    if (hit == true)
        Destroy (this.gameObject);
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "bullet") {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

I don't get why it stops to work so randomly.

Thanks in advance :)

Chrizzly

Comment: This won't help your problem, but I started reading your code and spotted that you are checking `if ( PinkPlayerControler.playerFaceRight == true ) { } else if ( PinkPlayerControler.playerFaceRight == false ) { }`. You can just use `if ( PinkPlayerControler.playerFaceRight ) { } else { }`. With a boolean, you don't need to add `== true`, as you could just keep going, viz. `if ( b == true == true == true == true == true )` etc. It'll make your code easier to follow.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks^^ I have to improve my coding at more than one part I guess

Comment: No problem... Regarding your actual question, it might be worth you reading "[*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" — there's a fair amount of code there, and it's a bit off-putting to read to try to find the source of the problem.